# How can I display images in Wordpress inbuilt the_title()?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display images in Wordpress inbuilt function the_title(). Please help.
My code:

```
<?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><img src="<?php echo (get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/line.png">','<img src="<?php echo (get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/line.png"></h3>' ); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but you can't nest `<?php` tags like that.  You'd need to concatenate the results of the inner call with the string outside it.  Something like: `<?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/line.png">','<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/line.png"></h3>' ); ?>`.  Are you trying to put your image both before and after the title?  Because (I think) that's what your code will do

Comment: Yes. exactly i want image before and after the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the_title() works like this:

```
<?php the_title( $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

By default `$echo = true` , so just pass the `$before` and `$after`

Use like this :

```
<?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/line.png">','</h3>' ); ?>
```

if the image is needed both before and after the title use this code below :

```
<?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/line.png">','<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/line.png"></h3>' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to add image in all title of project,its better to us the_title filter
(in given code, get_template_directory_uri() is used for parent theme, if you work in child theme then you have to change it with "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()")

```
function add_image( $title) {

$src = get_template_directory_uri().'/assests/images/header.jpg';

return $title.'<img src=" '.$src.' ">';
```

}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_image', 10);